# Is it still necessary to include non-Retina assets in iOS apps?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it necessary to use non Retina assets in new apps?

I am asking because they take up considerable space and they're a significant time sink in my design workflow. Nowadays in late 2012, the only supported non-retina devices are steadily dying out. According to my stats: `13.8%` of my users were on `iPhone 3GS or older` (including older iPhones and iPod Touches 3rd gen and below) during the month of September.

I'm not asking whether it's a good idea or not (sometimes it's good to create less detailed artwork for lower res devices).

**I just want to know whether only including @2x assets will work reliably on non-Retina displays and whether there's any implications?**

Comment: don't forget ipad 2, it is no retina. I will wait a bit longer to remove the no retina assets.

Comment: Depending on the style of your graphics, it may be entirely fine to include @2x versions only. Just doublecheck if those are still fine when using a non-retina device as they will be autoscaled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not necessary. iOS will downsample the 2X resources if you don't provide a 1X version (note that the simulator's downsampling is crappy but the devices are fine).

Comment: any links to documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Only including retina (@2x) assets works well **in general** on a non-retina device, but with really small assets (especially tiny icons with lots of small strokes) the results will be **clearly blurry and bad**. You should look at your app on a non-retina device, find assets that don't look great, and add non-retina versions for those.

Answer (score 0):

Its good if you include images with @2X in your code. we need to do this as apple still supporting its latest OS with devices like 3GS and iPod.

Comment: Your answer is pretty weird.